# FreePBX/Asterisk call-recording playback plays one stream at a time

Tags: asterisk, voip

I'm hitting a very odd issue with FreePBX 2.8.1.5 (yes yes I know; need to update - not that easy) with Asterisk 1.6.2.10.

I just enabled On-Demand call recording that is achieved by pressing *1 during a call. However - when I try to playback the call, it plays the incoming stream first in its entirety and then the outgoing stream in its entirety; it does not mix the two!

So for example: I talk to a colleague and I start the conversation by saying "How are you doing?" he would say "Ok" and then I would say "I will count to 5 - 1,2,3,4,5" to which he says "I will continue counting - 6,7,8,9,10."

When the call is terminated and I listen to the recording, what I hear first is my colleague saying "Ok" pause "I will continue counting - 6,7,8,9.10" and afterwards, I will hear my stream - "How are you doing?" pause "I will count...".

Obviously Asterisk is not mixing the streams but I've never encountered such behavior before with any version of Asterisk! Anyone has an idea of what's going on and how to potential resolve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hah - so looks like Sox was being naughty. Implemented a workaround found [here](http://community.freepbx.org/t/recording-calls-weird-problem-freepbx-2-7-0-1/8006/15) and it worked great.

Workaround:

Edit global_custom.conf and add the following:

```
MONITOR_EXEC=/var/lib/asterisk/bin/soxmix.sh
```

Then create the script (make sure to chown accordingly):

```
#!/bin/sh
nice -n 19 soxmix $1 $2 $3
if [ -s $3 ]
then
 rm -f $1
 rm -f $2
fi
```

Restart amportal/asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk can mix the recorded streams on the fly. You should look for DYNAMIC_FEATURES and change monitor to mixmonitor. Look around at /etc/asterisk/features*.conf